# RJ45 Split, one part Ethernet other part telephone.

Tags: rj45

I have a patch panel and some ports that allow me to patch telephones lines.

So, I use this patch panel to give a wired connection to some devices and I also use it to provide a telephone point.

The problem I have, I only have one socket at the location that I have our phone and I want the phone along with Ethernet to connect a Wireless Access Point eg :

[image]

I already have these :

[image]

And I do this

[image]

They work a treat and give me two network connections along one Structured cable. But they don't work for the landline.

*I apologies if I am using all the wrong words, I work in IT and I understand a little networking, if the landline only uses a few cables I guess I could make something, but I would rather buy something.*

Comment: Those adapters you have there connect 4/5 and 3/6 of the plug to both ports. These are for POTS and ISDN. You need adapters which connect 4/5 of the plug to one port and 1/2 and 3/6 of the plug to the other port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those splitters work because Ethernet (non-Gigabit, at least) only uses two of the four pairs (pins 1,2 and 3,6) of the RJ45 connector and cabling. So they put the same pins of the second connection onto the unused pairs of the first (pins 4,5 and 7,8) and then restore them at the other end. Here's an example:

[image]

But normal wiring for telephones over structured cabling uses one or two of the centre pairs (pins 4,5 and maybe 3,6) so the same adaptors won't transfer the correct connections across. As 3 and 6 WILL be carried correctly (because they are also used for Ethernet) you can assume that it's 4 and 5 you're missing. As you can see from the picture above, 4 and 5 aren't connected at all on the splitter you'd use in cable sharing for Ethernet.

If you can't buy something suitable you'll need to make up some adaptors of your own that connect them correctly.

A quick search on Amazon found [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DI4WYW) but it shows as unavailable, though I'm sure alternatives can't be too hard to find. You can see that it connects 1,2,3 and 6 for the network ("computer") and 4,5 for the phone.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I did a quick search but could not find anything :) there out of stock but now I know what terms to enter into google.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet uses two balanced pair (Rx/Tx) per port using up all 4 pairs per cable.

POTS Phone use one balanced pair per line with two landlines using two pair.

So you can have 1 of each or both of either type..... or only 4 POTs phone lines in theory.

I have yet to see a better solution except cordless phones and high power D-Link WiFi router ( which is what I use , with care in antenna placement ) So I don't use any house wiring.

### Edit

**If you have hot air heating, it may be time to start hauling cables down the cold air return registers.** Gentle with corner kinks. Start with dummy wire or maybe better, here's a thought, then **pull an old 100' garden hose** then pull the  CAT5/6 inside it, to protect from corner kinks that affect Zo.

I trust you have fibrenet to support the aggregate BW. :)

It seems the future is Routers such as [**Orbi**](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/best-wireless-routers/) with  **MU-MIMO WiFi** so a dedicated link to modem is not wasted.  Then there is the hefty **[Eero Pro](https://eero.com/shop/pro-wifi-system)** with ethernet ports on each WiFi hub.

We mainly use MagicJack to Router ( almost free phone & free LD in N.A.) , Kodi 17 addons for free web TV and free movies and an OTA antenna using HDHomerun tuner to router for local TV with 54" 1080p VGA port to tower. We have 4 grandkids  with mobiles and my new DLink spread +2/-1 floors is always >-50 dBm vs the old one sometimes near -80 dBm which is a thousand times lower power. ( Single hot 3 band WiFi )

### Ah yes. Need more ports and fewer octopii.

One ( 1 ) ethernet pre-wired per room is not enough, just like 3 AC outlets was normal per room but today is inadequate with all the octopus adapters. **Thank goodness for 6 port USB chargers**. Too bad USB power isn't included with every wall jack. My concept 10 yrs ago was central 48Vdc DC on the phone jack line2 for DC-DC adapters inside each device to get rid of all pesty little bricks. Also 48V is good for low power ambient LED lighting coming from the local battery charged from a nearby breaker panel.  I suppose .

Comment: our house is over 3 floors and we have a high demand for our network :) 4 kids and a home office so pure WiFi does not do it. We have most things wired them for WiFi we have a Deco M5 configured with a wireless backhaul. tbh, we never EVER EVER use the LANDLINE, but if I said to the wife it was not working she would tell me that she used it all the time :) The person who built the house was kind enough to put in a patch panel but I would have had wall ports in different places.